# Why are private variables of a class accessible from an object in the class?

Tags: c++, class, scope

Let's say we have a class with a single `private` variable and a `max` method that takes a single parameter of the same type of the class:

```cpp
class A
{
private:
    int Number;

public:
    A() : Number(0) {}
    A(int val) : Number(val) {}

    int max(A b)
    {
        if( Number > b.Number )
            return Number;

        return b.Number;
    }
};
```

What is strange to me is that the parameter `b` in the max method has access to the `private` variable `Number`. However in the `main` function we do not have access to the parameter `Number` (as expected since it is declared `private`)

```cpp
int main()
{
    A a;

    a.Number = 0; // ERROR

    return 0;
}
```

So my question is why does the function in the class have access to the variable `Number` when it is declared `private`.

Comment: That's what private is for. Externals have no access, internals have

Comment: It's fairly universal across object orientated languages that objects can access the private members of other objects of the same class

Comment: You begin your question with something about variable scopes. Private variables are not scope variables. Also, please elaborate which problem you see with the way it is.

Comment: Because otherwise private variables would be completely pointless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just the rule, that's all.

It's designed to make member functions, especially functions like assignment operators, copy constructors, and overloaded operators, simpler to write. If you couldn't access the members of the "other" object directly then you'd need a plethora of `friend` declarations or ugly "getters"; the latter tend to offer little more than a circumvention of encapsulation.

Perhaps the way you propose could have been the default, and to bring in the private and protected members and functions could have required the declaration

```
friend class;
```

But C++ was not designed this way, and that proposal would now be an hideous breaking change. Something to muse on though to recover your expected behaviour could be a declaration

```
friend class = delete;
```

which would, as far as I can tell, *not* be a breaking change. Why not propose something of this form to the ISO C++ Committee?

Answer (score 3):

The principle idea behind encapsulation is to hide the internals of a class from external classes.

When you consider that the function you're writing is internal to the class `A`, it makes sense for the function to be aware of `A`'s internals - regardless of the context.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. I thought it strange because I used to think objects had no access to private members of the class no matter where you use them.